# complex post parameter is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When i make post request to following action

```
[HttpPost]
public ResponseOutput Incremental(List<Product> inputList)
{
    return true;
}
```

parameter inputList is always null. My object:

```
public class Product
{
    public string ContractNo { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public double Alis { get; set; }
    public string Kur { get; set; }
    public string SupplierNumber { get; set; }
    public ActionType Islem { get; set; }
}
```

ActionType is enum.

And my request body:

```
POST /api/Konsinye/ConsigneeInsertIncremental HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:38664
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9e5f759c-552d-2e3e-f704-28ec91045e6c

{
 "inputList" : [
    {
      "ContractNo" : "123",
      "Sku" : "1234",
      "Alis" : "112",
      "Kur" : "TRY",
      "SupplierNumber" : "000",
      "Islem" : "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Problem is, parameter is always null. I tried adding [FromBody] to signature but it didn't help.

Comment: why does your controller say List<Product> inputList when type is ConsigneeProductInput? it should be List<ConsigneeProductInput> inputList isn't.

Comment: @Prashant That's my mistake when doing copy&paste. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this approach(transfer array of objects to the server instead of single object with array's property):

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Incremental(List<ConsigneeProductInput> data)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Body from Postman:

```
[
    {
      "ContractNo" : "123",
      "Sku" : "1234",
      "Alis" : "112",
      "Kur" : "TRY",
      "SupplierNumber" : "000",
      "Islem" : "1"
    }
]
```